# Quality Profile: The specified qualityProfile 'java-sonar-way-64367' does not exist

Tags: sonarqube

I just updated my SonarQube instance from 5.5 to 6.7.2 LTS, by taking care of migrating to 5.6.7 LTS before going to 6.7.2 LTS. Everything went smooth. Looking at the Quality Profiles, I see that the migration process imported/kept Quality Profiles from my old instance, and marked them as quality profile coming from the older version of SonarQube. Then I have marked the new Sonar way quality profiles (those with the built-in marker) as the Default Quality Profiles, and then cleared the old obsolety quality profiles.

Now, when looking at a project dashboard, I get this:

```
The specified qualityProfile 'xml-sonar-way-77200' does not exist
The specified qualityProfile 'java-sonar-way-64367' does not exist
The specified qualityProfile 'web-lsds-56954' does not exist
```

Looks like some kind of housekeeping was skipped when I changed the default quality profile to the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quality profiles shown on Project homepages are those last used in analysis of the projects. Run a new analysis (with the new profiles) and this should clear itself up.

Comment: Since we got 83 projects right now in SonarQube, is there a way to update those metadata from the backend (database)? Those projects are not necessarily all in development phase. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @CharlesMorin the only way to update the record of the last profile used in an analysis of the project is to reanalyze.